# Can a Marionette.View bind an event or trigger using an element id?

Tags: marionette

I have a simple Marionette.ItemView with a link on it:

```
<a id="login-link">login</a>
```

But when I bind an event or trigger in the view, the event does not fire:

```
triggers:
    "click #login-link" : "login:clicked"

events:
    "click #login-link" : -> console.log "login clicked"
```

Yet, if I identify the link using a class name, either of these works:

```
<a class="login-link">login</a>

triggers:
    "click .login-link" : "login:clicked"

events:
    "click .login-link" : -> console.log "login clicked"
```

So, are ids not a valid selector for binding triggers and events in a Marionette.View?

Answer (score 1):

id definitly can fire events in marionette.
I just put a small sample on jsfiddle so you can take a look. the error then may be somewhere else.

```
    var MainView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
         template: "#sample-template", 
         events: {
             "click #fireEvent": "eventWithId"
         },

         eventWithId: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.$el.find('#mytext').text('the id event changed my text!')
         }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rayweb_on/HTQGM/1/

Comment: Hmmmm, I see that it's working in your demo, and I can't seem to get it to break.  I also can't seem to get it to work in my application.  The substantive differences are that I've settled on using triggers instead of event (I modified your code to do that and it still works), AND I'm writing in coffeescript which might be altering things a bit.  I get no errors in my code, just no event triggering, and all I do is change the selector to use the class and it works.

Comment: well, the only think that come to my mind then is that perhaps there is an issue with versions. are you using both backbone and marionette 1.0?

Comment: Yes - I grabbed the latest when I started building a test project two days ago.

Comment: I'm voting up your answer for now, but will wait to figure out why the id selector isn't working in my project before accepting it as the answer.